# php - split switch cases in different files

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a php file in which i am using a really very long switch case. I want to split the cases in different files (keep logically connected cases in 1 file).

EDIT: Sorry everyone it was my code that was causing problem. The switch case was working as expected.

file -> a.php

```
echo "<br>RES = ".test(1);

function test($value) {
    switch($value) {
        case (1 || 2):
                include("b.php");
                            **return $temp;**
                break;

        default: echo "error";
                return 3;
                break;
    }
}
```

file -> b.php

```
switch($value) {

    case 1: echo "value is 1";
                    **$temp = 1;**
            return 1;
            break;

    case 2: echo "value is 2";
                    **$temp = 2;**
                    return 2;
                    break;
}
```

How do i get proper result? if the switch case of b.php is in a.php file then everything works fine.Any idea/suggestion on how to do this?

If i add $temp (bold lines) then it works...

Thanks for help in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated response to updated question: 
modify "a.php" and prefix a return infront of the "b.php" include:

```
return include("b.php");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

> Handling Returns: It is possible to
>   execute a return() statement inside an
>   included file in order to terminate
>   processing in that file and return to
>   the script which called it. Also, it's
>   possible to return values from
>   included files. You can take the value
>   of the include call as you would a
>   normal function. This is not, however,
>   possible when including remote files
>   unless the output of the remote file
>   has valid PHP start and end tags (as
>   with any local file). You can declare
>   the needed variables within those tags
>   and they will be introduced at
>   whichever point the file was included.

---

simple include()'s within your case/break sections?

```
switch($var)
{
 case 1:
   include('case_1.php');
   break;
 case 2:
   include('case_2.php');
   break;
 default:
   include('case_default.php');
  break;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for replying. I tried that but it didn't work. I have 5 cases in a file then how do i do it? Regards

Comment: Extrapolate on my example, since you didn't post any code examples I just gave you a generic structure for you to massage into your own system. use a different $var, if you want to match on strings use case "foo":

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I have editted my question to give some idea. Sorry initially i thought switch case is causing problem but its not like that. Regards

Comment: See now that's interesting, that looks like a bug in that the included file has some how lost that it's within a function and the return isn't behaving like expected.

Comment: Exactly... any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: as goofy as this sounds, try using... return include("b.php");

Answer (score 0):

This is actually something that Scuzzy proposed (I have even left the same naming convention), but improved:

```
// list of files
$my_files = array(
    'a' => 'case_1.php',
    'b' => 'case_2.php',
    'c' => 'case_3.php',
    'd' => 'case_4.php',
);

// determine which one to load
if (array_key_exists($var, $my_files)) {
    include($my_files[$var]);
} else {
    include('case_default.php');
}
```

or even shorter ;) :

```
$f = array('a','b','c','d');
include((in_array($var,$f)?$var:'case_default').'.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch($var)
{
    case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: //...
        include('case_' . $var . '.php');
        break;
    default:
        include('case_default.php');
        break;
}
```